# Deprecated method, what to use instead?

Tags: java, graphics, window, deprecated

The method `show();` in class Windows for java.awt in deprecated. What can I use instead?

```
package adventure;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.*;
// Infogar testkommentar mvh Holger 2012-06-20 kl 19.03
public class Adventure extends Frame  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID=100L;
    public Adventure() {        
    setSize(850, 440);    
    World world = new DungeonWorld ( this );        

    Person me = new Person( world, "You", null );    
    show();
    me.goTo("Dungeon");     
    add( new Player( world, me ) );    
    addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter ());    
    }

    class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter {

    public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }


    // Load an image from the net, making sure it has already been
    // loaded when the method returns
    public Image loadPicture ( String imageName ) {
    Image im = null;

    // Load the image from the net
    try {
        URL imageSource = new URL( "http://www...xxx/"
                       + imageName );

        try {
        im = createImage( (ImageProducer) imageSource.getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {}

    } catch (MalformedURLException e ) { }

    // Wait to ensure that the image is loaded
    MediaTracker imageTracker = new MediaTracker( this );
    imageTracker.addImage( im, 0 );
    try {
        imageTracker.waitForID( 0 );
    }
    catch( InterruptedException e ) { }

    return im;
    }


    // Load and play a sound from /usr/local/hacks/sounds/

    public void playSound (String name) {
    URL u = null;

    try {
        u = new URL("file:" +  "/usr/local/hacks/sounds/" + name + ".au");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e ) { }

    AudioClip a = Applet.newAudioClip(u);
    a.play();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {       
    System.out.println("test"); 
      new Adventure();
    }
}
```

Comment: As you know that the method is deprecated, you must have some access to the API. If you read the first phrase, you will see what to use instead...

Comment: I guess you should start reading the Javadoc first.

Comment: I know there is documentation but I wanted answer from a person. Sometimes a person knows more than the documentation. There are undocumented stuff here and there, for instance. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let's read the Java API for `Window#show()`: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#show%28%29)

```
@Deprecated
public void show()
```

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.5, replaced by `setVisible(boolean)`.
>
> Makes the Window visible. If the Window and/or its owner are not yet
>   displayable, both are made displayable. The Window will be validated
>   prior to being made visible. If the Window is already visible, this
>   will bring the Window to the front.

So you should use `Window#setVisible(boolean)` - for `show()` use `setVisible(true)`.

**EDIT**

In some environments just replacing `show()` with `setVisible(true)` changes the behavior of the application. This happens, when you wrote a subclass of `Window` that overrides `show()` (same for `hide()`).

So in your code example `setVisible(true)` does exactly the same as `show()`. But in general, just be certain, that no one overrides `show()` which wouldn't be executed anymore when using `setVisible(true)`. In such a case, you have to change the overriden methods, too.

Answer (score 5):

If you check the API you will see:

```
void show()
```

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.5, replaced by `setVisible(boolean)`.